# Show monthly or daily archives

Tags: archives, date-time, timestamp

My code is this:

```
#http://localhost/wordpress/2015/04/01
if (is_day()) {
}
//Prints January, April, 2015
#http://localhost/wordpress/2015/04/
if (is_month()) {
    echo single_month_title(' ');
//prints April 2015
}
#http://localhost/wordpress/2015/
if (is_year()) {

}
//prints 2015
```

What I want is, when an user is previewing a month archive it will show him the current date he is viewing...

I can already print the monthly one successfully, what I do not know if is there a WordPress function already to print the current day the user is viewing or the current month?

Answer (score 2):

Before Wordpress 4.1, you can show the date archive page titles with the following code: (*Taken and slightly modified from the twentyfourteen theme*)

```
if ( is_day() ) {
    printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date() );

} elseif ( is_month() ) {
    printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );

} elseif ( is_year() ) {
    printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );

} else {
    _e( 'Archives', 'twentyfourteen' );

}
```

As from Wordpress 4.1 you can use one of the following functions

- [`get_the_archive_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) which returns the titles
- [`the_archive_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_title/) which echos the titles to screen